# Spring MVC Validation with annotation not working in nested fields

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

Let's go straight to my classes Person.java

```
public class Person {

    @Size(min=4, max=10)
    private String name;

    @Range(min=0, max=80)
    private Integer age;

    @NotEmpty
    private String address;

    @Pattern(regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$")
    private String email;

    @Past
    private Date birth;

    private Pet pet;
...
}
```

and Pet.java

```
public class Pet {

    @NotEmpty
    public String name;
    @NotEmpty
    public Integer age;
...
}
```

and this is my form

```
   <form:form action="enter" method="post" commandName="personForm">
name:   <form:input  path="name"/>      <form:errors path="name" />     <br/>
age:    <form:input  path="age"/>       <form:errors path="age" />      <br/>
address:<form:input  path="address"/>   <form:errors path="address" />  <br/>
email:  <form:input  path="email"/>     <form:errors path="email" />    <br/>
birth:  <form:input  path="birth"/>     <form:errors path="birth" />    <br/>
petName:<form:input  path="pet.name"/>  <form:errors path="pet.name" /> <br/>
petAge: <form:input  path="pet.age"/>   <form:errors path="pet.age" />  <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/> <br/>
</form:form>
```

The code works well and shows message at form:error.. block when invalid values is entered except when it comes to petName and petAge.

Actually, the code doesn't validate petName and petAge at all.
I'm using hibernate validator. Could Someone tell me How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `javax.validation.Valid` annotation on top of `pet`.

```
public class Person {

    @Size(min=4, max=10)
    private String name;

    @Range(min=0, max=80)
    private Integer age;

    @NotEmpty
    private String address;

    @Pattern(regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$")
    private String email;

    @Past
    private Date birth;

    @Valid  // This line   
    private Pet pet;

}
```

Comment: See also this [example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e410)

Comment: Thank you, guys. Really helpful !